# OnLostFocus is called after dispose is called in a dataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I Have a control  inheriting the dataGridView control.
I have the onLostFocus method overrided. Lately I encountereda weird behavior. if trying to close the form while a cell is in teh middle of being edited. the dispose method will be called and then teh onLostFocus is called that results in a nullReferenceException

```
   protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e)
        {
           base.OnLostFocus(e);
          base.DefaultCellStyle = myStyle1;
            }
        }
```

my question is how come the lostFocus is called after the userControl starts being disposed?
and what is the correct way to handle this isuue?
A workaround can be to check explicitly if dispose had started and then return from the OnLostFocus. But I'd rather understans better what happens behind.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus.aspx, Microsoft suggested that `OnEnter` and `OnLeave` should be used instead of `OnGotFocus` and `OnLostFocus`.

> The GotFocus and LostFocus events are
>   low-level focus events that are tied
>   to the WM_KILLFOCUS and WM_SETFOCUS
>   Windows messages. Typically, the
>   GotFocus and LostFocus events are only
>   used when updating UICues or when
>   writing custom controls. **Instead the
>   Enter and Leave events should be used
>   for all controls** except the Form
>   class, which uses the Activated and
>   Deactivate events. For more
>   information about the GotFocus and
>   LostFocus events, see the WM_SETFOCUS
>   and WM_KILLFOCUS topics in the
>   "Keyboard Input Reference" section in
>   the MSDN library at
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/library.http://msdn.microsoft.com/library.

Comment: +1, correct.  Customizing DGV is in general painful with lots of unintended side-effects.